# How to run a program using a web extension's web worker as a compiler in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am currently working on a project where I need to run a program using Visual Studio Code with the help of a web extension. The compiler for this program is implemented within the web extension's web worker.

Just wondering if any example for this? I mean, the debugger is not need by now, just run the program in a web version VS Code.